# Поменять цвет кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Это меняется состояние, а нужен цвет кнопки

```js
$("#old").change(function(){
  $("#but").attr('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="old" >go
<button id="but">Нажать</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$("#old").change(function(){
  $("#but").toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="old" >go
<button id="but">Нажать</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Пойду дальше учить Javascript.

Comment: @Alex, рекомендую [Learn.JavaScript.Ru](https://learn.javascript.ru).

Comment: Спасибо. Бывают такие затыки - никак не понять, как работает та или иная функция - приходится разбирать часами до нитки